# Laravel 5 and Flysystem

Tags: laravel-5

I installed the extension https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem. I need to work with the  cloud (Dropbox). I set up parameters for flysystem.php Dropboks. But when I try to send a file - an error.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
...
Flysystem::connection('dropbox')->put('test222.txt', 'bar');
```

FatalErrorException in DropboxConnector.php line 69: Class 'Dropbox\Client' not found
http://clip2net.com/s/3l0Hwe1

What could be the problem?
Sorry for bad english and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed [Dropbox adapter](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-dropbox)?

```
composer require league/flysystem-dropbox
```

This will then install [Dropbox SDK for PHP](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php) which contain [Dropbox\Client](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/Dropbox/Client.php) class.